# Transform raw data into relational data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, etl

### Intro

I've been given a messy excel dump straight into a table. Now I need to turn that mess into something useful.
The dump has duplicates and inconsistencies... good times!

I've been striking out on every approach so far :( - Hope you can help me out.

Given this example data set:

```
ExcelDump
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |      |      | C    |
|  1 |      | B    | C    |
|  1 | A    | B    | D    |
|  1 | E    | B    | C    |
|  2 | A    | B    | C    |
|  2 | A    | B    | C    |
|  3 | A    | B    | C    |
|  3 | A    | B    | F    |
|  4 | A    | B    | C    |
|  4 | G    | B    | C    |
+----+------+------+------+
```

One possible result could be:

```
OutputTable
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | A    | B    | C    |
|  2 | A    | B    | C    |
|  3 | A    | B    | C    |
|  4 | A    | B    | C    |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Nice and neat.
Unique ID key and data merged together in a way that makes sense.

### How to choose which data is correct?

You've probably noticed that another possible result could be:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | E    | B    | C    |
|  2 | A    | B    | C    |
|  3 | A    | B    | F    |
|  4 | G    | B    | C    |
+----+------+------+------+
```

This is where it gets complicated. I want to be able to choose the set that makes the most sense based on some conditions I can manipulate.

For instance I want to setup a condition that says: **"Choose the most (non-null) common value, if no most common found take the *first* value found that is not null."**
This condition should be applied to the selection of grouped by IDs.
The result of that condition would be:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | A    | B    | C    |
|  2 | A    | B    | C    |
|  3 | A    | B    | C    |
|  4 | A    | B    | C    |
+----+------+------+------+
```

If I later find out that that assumption was wrong and it instead should be: **"Choose the most (non-null) common value, if no most common found take the *last* value found that is not null."**

```
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | E    | B    | C    |
|  2 | A    | B    | C    |
|  3 | A    | B    | F    |
|  4 | G    | B    | C    |
+----+------+------+------+
```

So basically I want to select values based a set of conditions on each group of IDs.

Comment: How did you choose the value `B` of `Col1` for `ID = 3` instead of `A`?

Comment: @Lamak also why is `Col1` `A` for `ID = 1` instead of `NULL`

Comment: @ConradFrix - I just assumed that op somehow was grouping by `Id` and for `ID = 1` there was just one row that has a value for a column different of `NULL` or empty. But is not the case for `ID = 3`

Comment: @Lamak good catch. I don't handle that atm, I suspect it's an error in the input data and either has to be corrected or deleted in the input. Not sure why I included it :/

Comment: @Lamak well you could also assume that the "last row" for a given ID was what was desired. This makes sense of `{3,B,Null,Null}`. Which makes the point indirectly that there are some undefined requirements that need to be clarified.

Comment: @ConradFrix - You are right, it is undefined how to best choose a row. Snabjorn, can you please clarify your requirements taking this comments on account?

Comment: @Lamak Ignore ID 3, I believe it has to be sorted before it's inserted. I'll delete it from the question as it's miss leading.

Comment: I believe your assumption is correct. The table isn't "refreshed" between operations in a MERGE. The rows that don't satisfy the MATCHED condition when the operation starts are not re-scanned to check whether changes made in the NOT MATCHED condition also suddenly made them eligible for MATCHED. I don't think there is any purpose to insert rows that don't exist, then update them with all the same values because now they do exist. :-)

Comment: What happens if you insert two more rows, `2 B C D` and `2 D C B`? What should the output for ID=2 look like?

Comment: @AaronBertrand that shouldn't happen, and if it does there are errors in the input data

Comment: Ok well it's very difficult to determine what you need on your larger data set when you've given us only very limited rows where things seem to line up very nicely. So for any given ID, across multiple rows, there will only ever be one letter or NULL/empty string in a column? So no column could have A and B for the same ID?

Comment: I see your point, I'll make a more elaborate example. But now I'll need to get some sleep :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've updated the question. Now it should explain in more detail what I need :) Sorry for simplifying the question too much in the first place, I tend to do that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified my solution to take into account the extra information added in the question.  The below query will get you the second sort priority you specified.  In order to get the first one, you'd change the "max" in the outer apply to "min" and change the "sortOrder desc" to "sortOrder asc".  Keep in mind if you have multiple ties for most frequent, say A,A,B,B,C and A came first, it would go with B in the below code because that was the highest count and came after the 2 A's.

```
-- setup test table
create table ExcelDump(
    id int
,   Col1 char(1)
,   Col2 char(1)
,   Col3 char(1)
)

insert into ExcelDump values(1,null,null,'C')
insert into ExcelDump values(1,null,'B','C')
insert into ExcelDump values(1,'A','B','D')
insert into ExcelDump values(1,'E','B','C')
insert into ExcelDump values(2,'A','B','C')
insert into ExcelDump values(2,'A','B','C')
insert into ExcelDump values(3,'A','B','C')
insert into ExcelDump values(3,'A','B','F')
insert into ExcelDump values(4,'A','B','C')
insert into ExcelDump values(4,'G','B','C')

-- create temp tables to make it easier to debug
select distinct
    id
into #distinct
from ExcelDump

-- number order isn't guaranteed but should be sorting them as first come first serve from the original table if no indexes exist
select
    row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as numberOrder
,   ID
,   Col1
,   Col2
,   Col3
into #sorted
from ExcelDump

-- actual query
select
    ui.Id
,   col1.Col1
,   col2.Col2
,   col3.Col3
from #distinct ui
  outer apply (
        select top 1
            ed.Col1
        ,   count(*) as cnt
        ,   max(ed.numberOrder) as sortOrder
        from #sorted ed
        where ed.id = ui.id
        and ed.Col1 is not null -- ignore nulls
        group by ed.Col1
        order by cnt desc, sortOrder desc -- get most common value, then get last one found if there are multiple
    ) col1
  outer apply (
        select top 1
            ed.Col2
        ,   count(*) as cnt
        ,   max(ed.numberOrder) as sortOrder
        from #sorted ed
        where ed.id = ui.id
        and ed.Col2 is not null -- ignore nulls
        group by ed.Col2
        order by cnt desc, sortOrder desc -- get most common value, then get last one found if there are multiple
    ) col2
  outer apply (
        select top 1
            ed.Col3
        ,   count(*) as cnt
        ,   max(ed.numberOrder) as sortOrder
        from #sorted ed
        where ed.id = ui.id
        and ed.Col3 is not null -- ignore nulls
        group by ed.Col3
        order by cnt desc, sortOrder desc -- get most common value, then get last one found if there are multiple
    ) col3
```

Comment: This looks something I might be able to use. Performance isn't an issue as this would be the transform step in ETL. I updated the question with a bit more detail, would you still say this is the best approach?

Comment: I've modified the answer I gave to take into account your updated question.  I wouldn't say this is necessarily the "best" approach as there is more than one way to skin a cat.  It is simply a way that will work.

Answer (score 3):

As written, you can do this with a simple `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    Col1 = MAX(Col1),
    Col2 = MAX(Col2),
    Col3 = MAX(Col3)
FROM
   ExcelDump
GROUP BY
   id
```

This pattern will give you the highest non-null value per column per id value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cursors to iterate through your temporary ExcelDump table to filter each row. You could store the filtered results into another temporary table that can have its own constraints like unique or not null if necessary and, by using cursors, you can write specialized code to handle every validation you require.